# Android App - improve performance in ARM

Tags: android

My app does a heavy processing in the background (using a asyntask) and it works fine in mobiles with X86 but in ARM is really slow (I tested in both real devices and emulator and it is the same performance). Well, the heavy background task is just comparing strings and numbers using two for loops. So, I wonder if there is something to configure in the compiler or somewhere in the project.

Below is an screenshot of traceview and I would like to ask you please to take a look to it and help me understand it.

[image]

Comment: Use Traceview and determine exactly where your time is being spent.

Comment: How about using NDK and optimizing your executable :P

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @jyoon how can I use NDK for this purpose? I barely have an idea what the NDK is for and I do not have any C++ or C# code in my project.

Comment: I personally don't have experience using NDK, but it is basically compiling executables instead of running your app as bytecode in the JVM. You will have to rewrite your whole project using C/C++, so I don't think this is a good option for you.*